# LINQ - Self join in list

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a List defined as below

```
 var MList = new List<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>();
(Example list item { "Prj1" ,  {e1,e2,e3} }
```

Ideally, a List item would contain a Project Name (string) and an array of admin ids (Object). I need to create and populate a new List with items which are expanded from the original list.

So the resulting list would look like below, with each item being a string.

```
{"Prj1","e1"}
{"Prj1","e2"}
{"Prj1","e3"}
```

How can i use LINQ to fetch items into the new list in the above format

Comment: Why is `Value` of type `object` instead of `String[]` if that is the type you are using it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your Object an `IEnumerable`?

```
var newlist = from x in mList
              from v in (IEnumerable<object>)x.Value
              select new
              {
                 x.Key,
                 v,
              };
```

Comment: Worked fine with IEnumerable<string> instead of IEnumerable<object>

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `SelectMany`, like this:

```
var expanded = MList.SelectMany(
    item => ((IEnumerable<string>)item.Value).Select( str =>
        new KeyValuePair<string,object>(item.Key, str)
    )
);
```

The above assumes that `Object` contains an `IEnumerable<string>`.